# Interfacing my PIC Microcontroller over USB and Controlling with my VB.NET application

Tags: vb.net, usb, microcontroller, pic, mikroc

Iam devoloping an embedded device using **PIC Microcontroller** (**PIC18F4550**).
Iam almost done with the hardware part. I need to control my device via **USB** using **VisualBasic 2010 Express**. Source code is compiled using **MikroC PRO**

My device belongs to an **USB HID** specification and its **VID=1234 and PID=4321**.

I tried many dll's but can't understand logic behind all.

What I need from my application is as follows...
1: Detect all USB devices connected to my PC
2: Detect wether my device(VID=1234,PID=4321) is connected or not
3: Send and recive commands
4: Send and recive Ascii values

Can any of my friends **suggest me which library** is the best and **how to use it** for the above tasks.

*Iam feeling complex using **WMI** to detect all USB devices. Iam prefering any librarys and the simplest way i can make use of it.

Any help is hopping..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `libusb` I think there's .NET wrapper libraries too.

Much more complicated than TTL usb-serial adapter, though.

Comment: Great help my friend. Let me check 4 it..!

Comment: Yeah. I downloaded it from https://jphonewin.googlecode.com/files/LibUsbDotNet.dll and Its usage is available in http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/html/6ab39c2b-8611-46bf-8066-bfe79ae9f1f9.htm. Thanks friend.!

Comment: Yeah. Its worth. But one thing more...!! before ticking green my friends...I can communicate with my device using MikroC HID terminal. But this code in VB.net dosen't find my device...! WHY??? ANY one please solve this..    ---->    http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/html/9926451f-29bf-4fae-9233-f6467ed072c7.htm    <----    This code dosen't detect my device. Please help..

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot help with your specific issue, I would need your USB device and some USB debugging.

Comment: How is your answer? Is it satisfactory?

Comment: Ok. But not too much.! I have got a new information from u buts thats not what iam querying

Comment: My answer responded to your original posting. It is not good etiquette to ask more questions in the comments. Especially ones so specific such that I would need your actual hardware and software to debug your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have something working this side of Christmas 2016 then use a USB-serial adapter between the PC and PIC chip.

This way you can use VB to talk via a COM port (serial port, UART, ...) and avoid USB completely.

Like this thing:

http://pages.ebay.com/link/?nav=item.view&id=141865394463&alt=web

Comment: Thats dosen't fit my needs my friend. I need to develop 6 device clones after the one I mentioned got success, Because Iam devoloping a security device so that 6 pcs is essential. Shopping for 6xUSB-COM converter dosen't sounds good for my vallet.

Comment: Ok I understand. It may cost you a lot more in time than 6*£4 to develop a usb direct solution.

Comment: In the PC side >     I have 2014 owned Desktop and 2015 owned Lap. Both dosen't have atleast 1 SERIAL port. I can't find any more SERIAL PORTS in my girlfriend's PC. Woah..! All those have many USB BUS's.<br>In the MCU side >    I need to reprogram and re-flash my PIC to migrate from USB(PC) to SERIAL(MCU) reciver. If Iam struggled 4 that. Then the USB feature of that special MCU PIC18F4550 gone unused...ANY OTHER WAY...?? Using just USB & VB.net

Comment: With that converter you do not need s serial port. That converter 'appears' in windows and linux as a simple serial port. This makes programming apps to use it quite simple. FTDI is very popular way of doing serial comms via usb to microcontrollers.

Comment: Oh..Thats a good idea. I have the circuit created in Proteus 8 PRO. Can you help me if using SERIAL PORT instad of USB, How can I simulate the ckt using my VB.net 2010 application?